# Inheriting from Silverlight Slideshow dll

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, xaml, inheritance

I am trying to use the .dll of a slideshow project and inheriting the xaml(from the slideshow prj) in a new project so that I have the xap file needed as source for the Silverlight  tag. In this way, I am trying to eliminate the need for including the Slideshow project(Source code) in the new project. Is this possible? If yes, please let me know how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found the Solution, yay.

I copied the ClientBin directory to my new projects clientbin directory. Now I can use any external project this way.. Why didnt I think of this any sooner?